# Calculate time difference between 2 columns when some times are after midnight

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff, date-difference

I have 2 columns `Startdate` and `Enddate` and would like to calculate the hours one worked "after hours". After hours is anytime between 16:00 and 03:00.

Everything works well when startdate is after 16:00 and before midnight. My current struggle is when Startdate is 10:45 and Endate is 02:00. Also when Startdate is 15:00 and Enddate is 04:00.

I used:

```
Case 
   when cast(Startdate as datetime) between '16:00' and 23:59 
      then Cast(Datediff(minute,Startdate, Endate)) 
      else 0  
end
```

Problem: Case when cast(Startdate as datetime)<'16:00' and cast(Enddate as datetime)>'03:00' then (Datediff(minute,('16:00', '03:00')) else 0 end

During Startdate 10:45 and Enddate 02:00 my ideal scenario would be to get 10hours as a result(from 4pm to 2am).

I'm new here, tried to summarise please let me know what other info I should provide. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Since these are type datetime, is the date also included, or available possibly in another column?  If not, can you manufacture dates, say 6/1/2020 and 6/2/2020 and use them?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question, specifically: "During Startdate 10:45 and Enddate 02:00 my ideal scenario would be to get 10hours as a result(from 4pm to 2am)." I think what you are looking for is a condition: `CASE WHEN Enddate < Startdate THEN DATEDIFF( minute, Startdate, DATEADD( hour, 24, Enddate )) END`. You may need to cast it to `DATETIME` format.

Comment: Thank you, casting as DATETIME worked perfectly